# ffmpeg - Making a Clean WAV file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, game-engine, wav

I'm looking to batch convert a number of files to audio files using `ffmpeg` for a game called `Star Wars: Jedi Knight: Dark Forces II`. The problem I'm having is that `ffmpeg` seems to be doing something that does so that `Jedi Knight` can't play the sound file.

`Jedi Knight` accepts plain old `PCM` `WAV` files of various ranges, from 5khz to 96khz, 8 and 16 bit, mono and stereo. This sounds plain and simple. Except for that if one were to create a `WAV` file using `MS Sound Recorder`, `Jedi Knight` could not play it. Speculation was that it added something extra to header or something. But it can play a `WAV` file created by `Audacity`, `GoldWave` or `ModPlug Tracker` to name a few.

So why not `ffmpeg`? Am I using the wrong codec or params? I took an original sound file from the game and performed the following:

```
ffmpeg -i "orig_thrmlpu2.wav" -f wav -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 1 "ffmpeg_thrmlpu2.wav"
```

The `ffmpeg` version does not play in the game. `ffprobe` shows that the `ffmpeg` version has some `Metadata` which the `original` doesn't have. What params should I use to try and get the same `WAV` format as the original? Mind you, `-ar`, `-ac` and `bits` aren't the important parts.

Here are the files for you to examine: http://www.edwardleuf.org/Games/JK/thrmlpu2.zip

Answer (score 28, accepted):

FFMpeg by default is adding a LIST-INFO chunk to the WAV output. Adding `-bitexact` suppresses it.

So,

```
ffmpeg -i "orig.wav" -f wav -bitexact -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 1 "ffmpeg.wav"
```

Comment: you can also try with "-flags +bitexact"

Comment: Actually, just `-bitexact` did not work in my version of ffmpeg. I had to use the flags as mentioned by Srounsroun.

Comment: The `-bitexact` was not enough for me. I wrote an answer on another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839572 where I mention the necessity to also use the `-map_metadata -1` option if you want to completely get rid of the `LIST` chunk.

Comment: I think I found that `-f wav` is also necessary (unable to check at the moment).

Comment: No. As long as the output extension is `wav`, ffmpeg will select the wav muxer.

Answer (score 3):

According to this feature request for ffmpeg to change its wav header files, the problem is 2 optional bytes. `cbSize` which are only supposed to be used for non-pcm data.

https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2013-April/142576.html

The header ffmpeg was writing as of 2013 was "80 bytes or 46 if you manage to suppress the LIST-INFO chunk."

The solution written there is to used these arguments when using ffmpeg.

> > I must use `ffmpeg -i ... -f s16le tmp.dat` and then `mplayer -demuxer rawaudio -rawaudio rate=44100:channels=2:samplesize=2 -ao pcm tmp.dat` to get "normal" wav file, many program can't read ffmpeg's wav file, they read 44 bytes of header, and others data use as sound, sometimes it caused broken byteorder, or they say that file is broken and can't read file at all. So I want get "correct" wav from ffmpeg directly. Sorry for my bad english :)

The method listed there might work if -bitexact is not applicable. For example when converting wav to wav in order to fix the header.