# What is the difference between these 2 wav files?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav, mediainfo

I am trying to use a program called *[arss](http://arss.sourceforge.net/)* to create a spectrogram from a wav file. I have 2 wav files, one works and the other does not (it was converted to wav from mp3).

The error that *arss* throws at me is:

> This WAVE file is not currently supported.

Which is fine, but I have no idea what parts of my wav file to change so that it *will* be supported. The docs don't help here (as far as I can tell)

When I run `mediainfo` on both wav files, I get the following specs:

working wav:

```
General
Complete name                            : working.wav
Format                                   : Wave
File size                                : 1.15 MiB
Duration                                 : 6 s 306 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 1 536 kb/s

Audio
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Codec ID                                 : 1
Duration                                 : 6 s 306 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 536 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 1.15 MiB (100%)
```

not working wav:

```
General
Complete name                            : not_working.wav
Format                                   : Wave
File size                                : 5.49 MiB
Duration                                 : 30 s 0 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 1 536 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf57.83.100

Audio
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Codec ID                                 : 1
Duration                                 : 30 s 0 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 536 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 5.49 MiB (100%)
```

Comparing the audio specs of both files, I can't tell any difference between anything other than the file size and duration. I even updated the Sampling rate of the non-working wav using `ffmpeg` so that it would match the working one at 48.0kHz, but no luck.

Any idea?

Both wav files are available [here](https://github.com/98mprice/wav-files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFmpeg, by default, writes a LIST chunk, with some metadata, before the data chunk. ARSS has a rigid parser and expects the data chunk to start at a fixed byte offset (0x24). FFmpeg can be told to skip writing the LIST chunk using the bitexact option.

```
ffmpeg -i not_working.wav -c copy -bitexact new.wav
```

Note that ARSS doesn't check for sampling rate, only that WAVs have little endian PCM.

Here's a related Q, not quite a duplicate, linked for future readers:

[ffmpeg - Making a Clean WAV file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39668146/5726027)

Comment: Thanks, perfect. Just to note for future readers, I had to use '-flags +bitexact'

Comment: Note for future readers, the OP's suggestion applies if your FFmpeg version < 4.0 or a git build from before Oct 2017. In which case, the exact solution is to add `-fflags +bitexact` which is a side-effect of the OP's suggestion.

Comment: @Gyan I'm confused, what is the difference between `-flags +bitexact` and `-fflags +bitexact`? Also I've seen commands using both in one line, `-flags +bitexact -fflags +bitexact`

Comment: The former is applied to encoders. The latter to muxers. `-bitexact` applies to both.

Comment: I have version `ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2` and the `bitexact` options do change the `LIST` hunk, but it's still there. Also the `-bitexact` as shown in the answer is not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

I have an older version of ffmpeg and the `-bitextact` option alone did not help *much*. That is, it did remove some of the data from the hunk, but the `LIST` hunk was still present with *other data*.

You may have to also ask for no metadata at all with the `-map_metadata` option like so:

```
ffmpeg ... -i <input> ... -flags +bitexact -map_metadata -1 ... <output>
```

*(The ... represent location with other command line options as required in your case)*

By adding the `-map_metadata -1`, it really removed everything and the `LIST` hunk is now fully gone.

Comment: The 3.4 series is 4 years old at this point. Not recommended for use.

Comment: @Gyan Unfortunately, my company is still on Ubuntu 18.04... I'm hoping that we'll soon switch to either 20.04 or directly to 22.04 once out.

Comment: Just get the first git master pkg from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/