# ARSS returns error "This WAVE file format is not currently supported"

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, spectrogram

I have tried to import a wav file into *ARSS*: http://arss.sourceforge.net/index.shtml

I get the above error.

Files:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X24eUOzOGa5uBUHFTtrSmzptIQTz-93l

I have tried the following commands with FFmpeg to create a "`clean`" wav, however, they have all failed.

```
ffmpeg -i "file.wav" -f wav -bitexact -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 1 "ffmpeg.wav"

ffmpeg -i file.wav -c copy -fflags +bitexact new.wav
```

Ffmpeg appears to convert successfully, but it still returns the same error message in *ARSS*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP in a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51841289) had a file without any metadata within the WAV, so `-bitexact` was sufficient. Your input has metadata, so that has to be removed as well.

```
ffmpeg -i file.wav -c copy -bitexact -map_metadata -1 new.wav
```